# Исключить строки из потока А, содержащиеся в потоке B

Tags: строки, shell, grep, sed

Есть два потока: A и B. Оба получаю в виде результата работы shell-скрипта. Каждый из них содержит набор строк через line separator.

Хочу отфильтровать А, оставив только те строки, которых нет в B. Можно удалить, можно заменить на "" – оба варианта подходят.

Предполагаю, что можно использовать sed:

```
A | sed 's/\(B.string1|B.string2|... \)//'
```

Но не вполне представляю, как преобразовать поток в регулярное выражение.

UPD: [нашел вариант с `grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23179210/2790048):

```
grep -F -v -f список_исключений фильтруемый_список
```

Работает с файлами, но не работает с выводом от команд. Какой синтаксис нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если строки (в обоих списках) отсортированы в алфавитном порядке, то можно воспользоваться, например, программой `comm` (см. `man comm`). если не отсортированы, то — программой `grep` (пример ниже).

пример. есть два файла:

```
$ cat a
a
b
c
$ cat b
a
z
```

можно вывести строки, уникальные для первого из них, можно для второго:

```
$ comm -2 -3 a b
b
c
$ comm -1 -3 a b
z
```

сравнивать можно не только файлы, но и потоки, формируемые командами:

```
$ comm -2 -3 <(cat a) <(cat b)
b
c
```

аналогично и для программы `grep`:

```
$ grep -F -v -f <(cat b) <(cat a)
b
c
```

**Важно:** Пустая строка считается `grep` подходящей (matching) к любой строке. Поэтому, если в первом списке есть пустая строка или поток пуст, то результат фильтрации будет нулевой.

Comment: Отлично! синтаксис для потоков как раз и был мне нужен). Есть какое-нибудь руководство толковое по основам shell?

Comment: `man comm`: "reads file1 and file2, which should be sorted lexically..." – это вроде как не мой случай.

Comment: *Есть какое-нибудь руководство толковое по основам shell* — большинство изложенного в `man bash` применимо и для других `shell`-ов. по поводу подстановки результатов работы процессов в виде аргументов (вместо файлов) другим программам (если они поддерживают чтение из дескрипторов `/dev/fd/*`) можно прочитать в разделе *process substitution*.

Comment: Забыл тут плюс поставить. Еще раз уточню про comm: мне кажется, он только для сортированных списков подходит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, для сортированных. пожалуй, надо это упомянуть в ответе. **обновление**: упомянул.

Comment: Кстати, обнаружил, что `grep` не работает, если первый список пуст (пустая строка подходит к любой строке из второго списка).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, подобных частных случаев можно, наверно, ещё много придумать/обнаружить, но «пиши про всё» — это уже будет не ответ, а цельная статья.