# найти общие строки из двух файлов

Tags: bash, shell, grep

подскажите как в ubuntu с помощью grep выдернуть только нужные строки из файла.
есть два файла 1.txt (2 милиона строк), 2.txt (400000 строк)
в 1.txt список строк которые нужно проверять на вхождение строк из 2.txt
если в 1.txt находим строку из 2.txt то добовляем в файл 3.txt всю строку.

Comment: 1. строки должны полностью совпадать? 2. порядок строк имеет значение?

Comment: должно совподать только наличе строки из 2.txt в строке 1.txt

Comment: порядок не меет значения

Comment: 1.txt
вася любит машу
даша дура
Люся шкура

2.txt
вася
дура


3.txx
вася любит машу
даша дура
</code>

Comment: про порядок я спрашивал на предмет того, можно ли отсортировать файлы. тогда к ним можно было бы применить `comm` и получить *точные* совпадения строк. но такое решение работало бы, по моим представлениям, дольше того, что я предложил в ответе. к тому же в вопросе речь именно о `grep`. кстати, а для чего служит метка *awk*?

Comment: к слову: в комментариях не работает разбивка на строки.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Исключить строки из потока А, содержащиеся в потоке B](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438523)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если достаточно вхождения строки из `2.txt` в строку из `1.txt`, то можно, например, так:

```
$ grep -F -f 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt
```

пример:

```
$ cat 1
1
2
3
55
$ cat 2
3
4
5
$ grep -F -f 2 1
3
55
```

Comment: файд 3.txt после запуска grep -F -f 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt пустой :(

Comment: если при этом нет сообщений об ошибках, то могу предположить по крайней мере три объяснения: 1. в файлах нет общих строк. 2. в одном или двух файлах строки разделяются не таким символом(-ами), который ожидает *grep*. 3. под именем *grep* выступает не *gnu/grep* более или менее актуальной версии, а что-то экзотическое. например, вообще не *grep*, а какой-нибудь урезанный заменитель.

Comment: 1. в файле 1.txt точно есть строки с вхождением из 2.txt
2. окончание строк \n
3. grep -V grep (GNU grep) 2.16
бьюсь уже второй день, пробовал делать выборки при помощи вин софта KeyWordKeeper но в связи с тем что в 2.txt много строк (400к) KeyWordKeeper 18 часов только учитывал строки для выборки, в итоге не хватило памяти.

Comment: *в файле 1.txt точно есть строки с вхождением из 2.txt* — уточните, пожалуйста, что куда входит. в `1.txt` есть строка типа `12345`, а в `2.txt` есть строка типа `234`?

Comment: тут пример сделал http://pastebin.com/0p4qyVq4

Comment: пример у вас выполняется? значит, он кардинально отличается от того, что у вас записано в файлах.

Comment: проблемма решилась, все дело было в разных кодировках